# How to modify the access rights of the .rdata section of a PE loaded in memory?

Tags: c, windows, memory, memory-management, portable-executable

I'm learning how a PE files works (its structure and also how it works when the sections are mapped into memory).

Actually, I'm trying to modify the access rights of the `.rdata` segment (basically readonly) of a PE loaded into memory (I would like to add a write access on this memory region).

Here is my code (developped in C):

```
unsigned char* data = "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05";
printf("Data value before modification: %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X\n", data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4]);

SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo;
GetSystemInfo(&sysInfo);
uintptr_t pageStart = (uintptr_t)data & ~(sysInfo.dwPageSize - 1);

DWORD oldProtect;
if (!VirtualProtect((LPVOID)pageStart, sysInfo.dwPageSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect)) printf("GRRRRRR\n");
data[4] = 0x17;
printf("New value of data: %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X\n", data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4]);

data[2] = 0x43;
printf("New value of data: %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X\n", data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4]);

while (1) {
    if (!VirtualProtect((LPVOID)pageStart, sysInfo.dwPageSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtect)) printf("GRRRRRR\n");
    data[4] = 0x17;
    printf("New value of data: %02X %02X %02X %02X %02X\n", data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4]);
    Sleep(1);
}`
```

Here is the output of my program:

```
Data value before modification: 01 02 03 04 05
New value of data: 01 02 03 04 17
New value of data: 01 02 43 04 05
New value of data: 01 02 03 04 05
New value of data: 01 02 03 04 05
New value of data: 01 02 03 04 05
```

I don't understand why the two first attempts (before the infinite while loop) "works".
I don't understand why inside the infinite loop it doesn't work too.
And I also don't understand why on the second attempt, `data[4]` is reinitialized.
The return values of `GetLastError()` are **0**.

Thank you in advance for your help,

My goal is to dynamically modify the access rights of the `.rdata` segment of my PE loaded into memory.

I want to specify that I **absolutely do not want** to use char arrays (or unsigned char arrays) or even memory allocation (malloc or VirtualAlloc...).

I only want to be able to write in the segment corresponding to the mapping of the `.rdata` section in memory.

My work is only for educational purpose because I am interested in the `Windows loader`.

Comment: You could ask the O/S what it thinks is wrong by calling GetLastError().

Comment: @500-InternalServerError the returned value of GetLastError() is 0

Comment: Do you call it after `VirtualProtect()` but before `printf()`?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I called it between each line of my program. All the return values are 0. However, I noticed that when I'm calling a function (GetLastError for example) between the modification of the data variable and the corresponding printf, the value of data is also reinitialized

Comment: @user16196636 If I try your code, the first attempt fails. Memory access error. The loop works perfectly fine. So I wonder why, but I guess your compiler does things to help your code run? Maybe it copies data to a writeable section because it detects that you write to it? The reason for restoring the data[4] is a big question as well. Maybe you can look at your compiler options and disable some smart optimization options? You can also disassemble the compiled program to see what's really going on. Either way, it's not Windows that causes this behavior, at least I've never seen this before.